# Using jQuery deferred to chain asynchronous functions does not wait for first function to complete

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I'm trying to use jQuery (2.1) `$.Deferred` to chain functions together using `then`.

I've read through the docs and pretty sure I'm making a stupid mistake somewhere, but I cannot get function `second` to wait for `first` to complete.

```js
function first() {
  let deferred = $.Deferred();
  setTimeout(function() { // Any async function.
    $('ul').append('<li>First</li>');
    deferred.resolve();
  }, 500);
  return deferred.promise();
}

function second() {
  let deferred = $.Deferred();
  $('ul').append('<li>Second</li>');
  deferred.resolve();
  return deferred.promise();
}

$(function() {
  $.when(first()).done().then(second());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
</ul>
```

In reality, I want to keep chaining (hence the promise in `second` as well).

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jdb1991/n3aory8c/

How can I make this work correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the brackets `()` on the `second` function inside your `then()` callback. Otherwise you will execute the `second` function directly and not when the promise resolves.

```
$.when(first()).done().then(second);
```

**[Working example.](https://jsfiddle.net/n3aory8c/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there's no point in using `$.when()` at all when you only have one promise.  Just use `.then()` directly:

```
 first().then(second);
```

And, for `second`, you have to pass a function reference which means you pass just the function name.  If you have `()` after it, that executes immediately and passes the return result rather than just passing the function reference that can be called later by the `.then()` infrastructure.

`$.when()` is really only useful when you have multiple promises and you want to know when all of them are done.  When you just have a single promise, you can just use `.then()` directly on that one promise.  Note, I switched to `.then()` which is the ES6 standard way to use promises (and supported by jQuery) rather than use the jQuery specific `.done()`.